# Хэш в url на русском

Tags: url, кириллица, хеширование

Можно ли писать `hash` в `URL` на русском языке, например `#тест` в место `#test` или в каких-то браузерах это не будет работать, может ещё какие-то проблемы могут возникнуть, при использовании русских букв и пробелов в url hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать хэш на кириллице в принципе можно. Только учитывайте, что IE может её перекодировать.

Например, из `http://localhost/#три` в `http://localhost/#%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8`

Аналогичная ситуация может иметь место и при вставке такой ссылки на некоторых сайтах, если человек решит поделиться ссылкой на интересный материал.

> пробелов в url

Пробелы в URL запрещены, если нет перекодировки.

Comment: *Пробелы в URL запрещены.* - `%20`?

Comment: Речь идёт об использовании в чистом виде, а не перекодировке. А, вообще пробел в адресе - дурной тон. Лучше уж использовать традиционные заменители.

Comment: но все равно же де-факто разрешены

Answer (score 1):

в URL можно писать все что угодно если перед выводом обработать текст PHP-функцией urlencode: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php